# Please explain the meaning of N in this Venn Diagram.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[image: what does the N=16 mean]

Can someone explain what N means in this diagram? I am new to venn diagrams, and I was able to solve questions based on this Venn diagram without knowing what N means. But I am curious to know what it means.

Comment: Perhaps it is the number of elements in the complement of A, B, C

Comment: @Some1 or just a number not in A, B or C

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is the number of elements, or the cardinality of $\xi$. I have seen this notated as $n(\xi)$ before, but never as a capital.